# Trait does not conform with type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, types

I am having some issues with types.
In this case I have two traits with base methods, and one of them depends on the other.
After that I have two implementations for them.
Do you have any idea what is wrong here?

The compiler is saying:

```
type arguments [ImplDefinition,ImplDto,ImplDtoIdentifier] do not conform to trait ChildOperations's type parameter bounds [C <: Types.BaseT[A,I],A <: Types.IDObj[I],I <: IIdentifier]
[error] class ImplOperations extends Parent2(new ImplDefinition) with ChildOperations[ImplDefinition, ImplDto, ImplDtoIdentifier] {
```

The code:

```
/*
 * Generic Implementation
 */

object Types {

  type IDObj[I <: IIdentifier] = AnyRef {def id: I}

  type BaseT[A, I <: IIdentifier] = Parent1[A] {
    def id: Foo[I]
  }

}

trait IIdentifier extends Any {
  def id: Long

  override def toString = id.toString
}

class Parent1[A](a: String)

class Foo[A](a: String)

trait ChildDefinition[A <: Types.IDObj[I], I <: IIdentifier] {
  self: Parent1[A] =>

  def id(a: A): Foo[I]

}

class Parent2[A](a: A)

trait ChildOperations[C <: Types.BaseT[A, I], A <: Types.IDObj[I], I <: IIdentifier] {
  self: Parent2[C] =>

  def get(identifier: I): Option[A]
}

/*
 * Concrete Implementation
 */

case class ImplDtoIdentifier(id: Long) extends IIdentifier

case class ImplDto(id: ImplDtoIdentifier, name: String)

class ImplDefinition extends Parent1[ImplDto]("Value") with ChildDefinition[ImplDto, ImplDtoIdentifier] {
  override def id(a: ImplDto): Foo[ImplDtoIdentifier] = ???
}

class ImplOperations extends Parent2(new ImplDefinition) with ChildOperations[ImplDefinition, ImplDto, ImplDtoIdentifier] {
  self =>
  override def get(identifier: ImplDtoIdentifier): Option[ImplDto] = ??? // here I will use the id method from ImplDefinition
}
```

Comment: Personally, I wanted to take a look and give you a hint, but I don't have enough time to figure out everything that's going on here. You have 11 classes/traits, and that's excluding the extra types. You'll have a much bigger chance of a good response if you narrow your example down to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I already did this snipet and removed all the remaining parts. But you are right it is still huge. Not sure if it helps but, if you remove the class ImplOperations it compiles. The problem is verifying the ChildOperarions types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem seems to be the signature of the `id` def in `ImplDefinition`.
`Types.BaseT` asks for a `def id: Foo[I]` but `ImplDefinition` only provides a `def id(a: ImplDto): Foo[ImplDtoIdentifier]`
if you add a `def id:Foo[ImplDtoIdentifier] = ???` to the `ImplDefinition` class things will compile:

```
class ImplDefinition extends Parent1[ImplDto]("Value") with ChildDefinition[ImplDto, ImplDtoIdentifier] {
  def id:Foo[ImplDtoIdentifier] = ???
  override def id(a: ImplDto): Foo[ImplDtoIdentifier] = ???
}
```